# Find $z$ of a point in a plane in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d

Say for example, I have 4 points which I know the coordinates to, how can I find a fifth point that lies somewhere within them?

E.g, if $A(0,0,a)$, $B(1,0,b)$, $C(1,1,c)$ and $D(0,1,d)$ lie in a square, how can I find the point $P$ that lies at $P(0.6,0.35,p)$?

I've tried using proportion to work out how far along a particular side, and then how far into the square it is, but I'm always getting something wrong somewhere.

Here's an example of what I mean : [image: Example]

If I know the 4 points on the edge, how can I find any point inside?

(That is 3D, it just doesnt look like it)

Comment: (1) Is your problem only the z coordinate or also whether the point is side the shape? (2) Can you be sure the four given points are in the same plane? (3) Are you familiar with vectors?

Comment: I do know vectors, however today is the first time i heard of planes. The problem is the z-coord, i can find all the rest. Also, i know the z-coords of the points ABCD in my example, i just would have liked an example that used variable z-coords for the outside points.

Comment: Imagine $a=b=c=0$ and $d=1$. Then your four points form a (non-regular) tetrahedron and there may be many or no points inside it with given x and y. Also, even if $A,B,C,D$ form a quadrilateral in space (that is, they all lie on the same plane), I do not think they will form a square unless $a=b=c=d$.

Comment: Right... Does that change my question entirely then? It looks like it, because i have 4 connected points in space and need to find a 5th point that lies between them...

Answer (score 1):

[edit]The basic idea is this: On the line of real numbers, to get from, for example, $a=2$ to $b=5$, one needs to go $b-a=3$. If one goes only halfway, one ends up at $a+(b-a)\cdot\frac{1}{2}=3.5$. To get to $4$, one needs to go two thirds of the way, as $4=a+\frac{2}{3}\cdot(b-a).

These consideration you can apply independently for each dimension in space: To get from point $A$'s x-coordinate to point $B$'s x-coordinate, how far do I need to go? If I go instead only to $P$'s x-coordinate, which fraction of the way is this? 
But when you actually go from $A$ towards $B$ until your x-coordinate equals $P$'s, the y-coordinate will probably not be right. However, with the right combination of also "going" towards another point (that, importantly, is not on the $A$-$B$-line), one can get the combination right, which is what I outlined below.
[/edit]

Take three points in space, say $A(x_a,y_a,z_a),B(x_b,y_b,z_b),D(x_d,y_d,z_d)$.
Then $\vec{AB} = (x_b-x_a,y_b-y_a,z_b-z_a)$, $\vec{AD}$ analoguously.

Now, if you start at a, go in the direction of B, but maybe not all the way, say only $0\leq s\leq 1$, where do you end up? Or if you go from A to D, but only $0\leq t \leq 1$? And if you go first towards B, then parallel to $AD$? You always end up inside the parallelogram that is defined by the points A, B and D. And the coordinates of the point are $A + s\cdot\vec{AB}+t\cdot\vec{AD}$.

Or written differently:

$x_a(1-s-t) + sx_b+tx_d = x_p$

$y_a(1-s-t) + sy_b+ty_d = y_p$

$z_a(1-s-t) + sz_b+tz_d = z_p$

Given $x_p$ and $y_p$, you can solve the first two equations for $s$ and $t$ and then find $z_p$ with the third. Even better, with arbitrary real $s$ and $t$ you can test whether any other given point is in fact on the same plane as $A$, $B$ and $D$, i.e. whether they actually form a quadrilateral.

Comment: I'll come out and say that i'm in college, and i've not learned any of this yet, i've only recently found out what vectors are, and not seen any of this calculating them before

Comment: I know, I saw your age in your profile. :) Have you seen [systems of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) before? I would have added some more wikipedia links, they may not be helpful beyond the the introduction before the table of contents (e.g. [Coplanarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity). Some things that come up when googling "vectors introduction" look more helpful.

Comment: Nope, not seen that, i just recently did intergration and differentiation of curves, and the systems of linear equations thing went right over my head, just looking at it. Edit : after a further look, it looks like simultaneous equations and i've done that, the plane picture at the side just put me off